# all spaces replaced by tabs when ctrl+shift+f

Tags: eclipse, jsp

working in eclipse,when I type 'tab',it insert 4 spaces,it works well.but after ctrl +shift +f to format,all the 4 space will been replaced by tabs.how to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter: Edit Active profile->Indentation->Tab Policy: Select Spaces

You can't change the default profiles so you must provide a new profile name, then press the Apply button, then the Okay button.  It may help to press the Apply button once you have returned to the Formatter screen. Go back and look at the Tab Policy again to verify that your changes were saved.

Answer (score 1):

Including the above suggestions, I recommend searching for code style or style to get to the coding standard being applied with the user requests formatting of the code.  It is possible that the code style uses tabs instead of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that currently works is to use **Ctrl-A Ctrl-X Ctrl-V** on all code after using **Ctrl-Shift-F**. This will replace all tabs with spaces.

Comment: Not true, you can change the code style like @user1848921 said so that it converts tabs to spaces when using **Ctrl-Shift-F**

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which version of Eclipse you are using but for 
Eclipse 3.6 (for example) you may go to

`Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Insert spaces for tabs`

This will change Eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs

Comment: Unfortunately, this (and all other suggestions on this post) doesn't fix the ctrl+shift+f issue. Year 2014, Eclipse Luna

Comment: Still not fixing the issue; Year 2018

Comment: @bfrguci you are welcome to open a ticket with Eclipse Foundation

Answer (score 0):

The place in the Preferences may be different depending on which version of Eclipse you use.  If you load the preferences window you can use the search function there to find "Formatters" and set your preferences for different types of files, or generally.